# Generate PDF417-Barcode with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode, jasperserver

I try to generate a PDF417 barcode with *iReport*. The problem is that the String that I give the barcode contain "german umlauts" like ä,ö or ü. This umlauts can not be encode by the barcode.

This is my template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20"
              rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="432" y="189" width="148" height="75"/>
                <jr:PDF417 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components"
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd"
                           moduleWidth="38.0" textPosition="none" quietZone="2.0" verticalQuietZone="2.0" minColumns="7"
                           maxColumns="7" minRows="5" widthToHeightRatio="2.0" errorCorrectionLevel="4">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["äöüÄÖÜß Test Test"]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:PDF417>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
```

My Question is: If anyone know why this happens or what I can do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Import class com.barcodelib.barcode.BarcodeJasperFactory into your Jasper Reports report file.

```
<import value="com.barcodelib.barcode.BarcodeJasperFactory"/>
```

Insert barcode image into the right place in your report.

```
<image scaleImage="Clip" hAlign="Center"> 
<reportElement x="50" y="110" width="515" height="120"/> 
<graphicElement/> 
<imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable">
 <![CDATA[new com.barcodelib.barcode.BarcodeJasperRenderer
                          (BarcodeJasperFactory.createLinear(13, "0470821632"))]]></imageExpression>
```

See more: [how to use bar code in jasper reports in java](http://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/barcode_symbologies/barcode_jasper_reports.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a '['. Try using

> [!CDATA[[äöüÄÖÜß Test Test]]]

(without ")

More info here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Another option could be use an image and barcode generator like showed [here](http://www.keepdynamic.com/barcoding/barcode-jasper-reports.shtml)